# How to determine the font being used by a ttk.Button in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I have a ttk button whose font I want to know. Using: `my_button.cget('font')` gives me `_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-font"`. Alright, that means the widget itself is not storing the font. So I try to query the style instead with `my_style.cget('font')`. Then the result is `AttributeError: 'Style' object has no attribute 'cget'`.

Here is a code snipet. This time I tried to directly change the font. I know it's calibri but can't query it:

```
my_style = ttk.Style()
my_style.configure('W.TButton', background='black',
                   font=('calibri', 10, 'bold', 'underline'), foreground='white')
print(my_style.cget('font'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `my_style.lookup("W.TButton", "font")` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use also:

```
my_style.configure('W.TButton', 'font')
```